# Bone not moving with mesh correctly

Tags: bones

I added some armatures to an array and whenever I move any bones on it only the bones move and not the mesh. But when I move the first bone it moves the whole thing along with all the bones. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have your parented With Automatic Weights? Maybe share your file so that we can have a look? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes i have parented with the auto weights

Comment: please share your file?